# JavaScript Run function only if its the last time its being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue using a Javascript function to update a bootstrap spinner, in general it works fine, the issue comes when i do multiple clicks, i use ajax to update the quantity of the products selected for the cart.

If i click just once in the button it works good, but if click multiple times to increase the quantity by 10 then the function is executed 10 times and that generates 10 responses. It's kinda annoying.

This is the function:

```
    var contador = 0;
        function UPDATE_SUM(cant,modo,precio,prod_id,inv_id,lim){
    var canti = document.getElementById(cant).value;
    var quantity = canti;
    if(modo == "up"){
        var cantidad = parseInt(canti) + 1;
        if (cantidad > 0 && cantidad <= lim){
            quantity = cantidad;
            document.getElementById(cant).value = quantity;
            x.request('r:ajax/u.php?cant='+cantidad+'&id='+prod_id+'&inv='+inv_id+'; rl:resp');
        }
    }else if(modo == "down"){
        var cantidad = parseInt(canti) - 1;
        if (cantidad > 0){          
            quantity = cantidad;
            document.getElementById(cant).value = quantity;
            x.request('r:ajax/u.php?cant='+cantidad+'&id='+prod_id+'&inv='+inv_id+'; rl:resp');
        }
    }
    console.log("UPDATE_SUM "+contador);
    var precio = parseFloat(precio);
    var sub_total = precio*quantity;
    contador++;
    setTimeout(function(){
        updtQty(prod_id,sub_total,quantity);
    },1000);
    calcSeguro();
    calcTurcoSafe();
    var envio = document.getElementById('inpenvio');
    var turcosafe = document.getElementById('inpturcosafe');
    var seguro = document.getElementById('inpseguro');
    TOTALIZAR(envio,turcosafe,seguro);
}

function updtQty(id,sub_total,qty){
    contador--;
    console.log("updtQty "+contador);
    if(contador == 0){
        $("#resp").fadeIn().delay(5000).fadeOut();
        document.getElementById('sub_total'+id).innerHTML = 'Bs. '+decimales(sub_total,2);
        document.getElementById('subt'+id).value = sub_total;
    }
}
```

This is the handler:

```
<div class="custom-quantity-input">
                        <input type="text" name="cantidad[]" id="cant6" value="1" readonly="">
                        <input type="hidden" name="subtotal[]" id="subt6" value="135000">
                        <a href="javscript:;" onclick="UPDATE_SUM('cant6','up','135000','6','1','25');" class="quantity-btn quantity-input-up"><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></a> <a href="javascript:;" onclick="UPDATE_SUM('cant6','down','135000','6','1','25');" class="quantity-btn quantity-input-down"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a></div>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I don't see the event handler in your question, but I'll make the assumption that every `click` binds another event to the button. Create a fiddle so we can give you a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i've updated the code, you can see the handler there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't execute the animation in the `UPDATE_SUM` method. Instead, create a new counter variable outside of the function, increment it inside `UPDATE_SUM` and defer the animation to a new function with a 500ms delay (so increment the counter by one and call the new function with a 500ms timeout/deferral). Inside the animation function, decrement the counter by one and only execute the animation if the counter has reached 0. This will ensure that the animation only plays once if the user clicks on the button faster than once every 500ms. You can play with the timeout duration to better suit your UX.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, i think this is the better way. I'm gonna try it and report back. Thanks again

Comment: Please check my code, i've updated the question with your advise but the counter is not working.

Comment: Done! thanks a lot for your answer, i've updated the code in the question.

Comment: In my case I am calling multiple AJAX and want to call my relaunch function only when the last AJAX promise is fulfilled. As of now, the only solution I found is the counter. Is there a possibility of a better way to this?

Comment: @Abhi The counter is probably a pretty good solution in your case.